# Move newly created Google Doc to folder or create new folder based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

I am using a script to automatically create a new Google Doc and fill it with values from a spreadsheet.

My goal is, after creating and completing the doc, to either create a new folder based on the content in column E of my spreadsheet if a folder with that name does not exist yet and save the doc in the new folder. If such a folder already exists, I want to save the doc in the existing folder.

```
function createNewGoogleDocs() {

const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById();
const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById();
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Overview');
const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
//Start processing each spreadsheet row
rows.forEach(function(row,index) {
if(index === 0) return;
if (row[16]) return; //Check if a document has already been generated
const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`name`, destinationFolder);
const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
const body = doc.getBody();

body.replaceText('{{Customer}}',row[4]); // then I just start repeatedly replacing the placeholders in the Google Doc template

doc.saveAndClose();
const url = doc.getUrl();
sheet.getRange(index +1,17).setValue(url)
})
}
```

Comment: Try using recursion.  You could find all of the folders in your drive and put their names and id's in a spreadsheet and then you can search a simple list and record all the new names as you proceed further.

Comment: Can you share sample/copy of your spreadsheet file? Remove sensitive data if any.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. Use [Markdown Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892)-all the data needed to answer your question must be in the question itself. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Is there is problem with the code included in the question?